# How do you deal with typedef and a Map?

Tags: flutter, dart

For use in a package,
I want to create a new set of typedef:
`IconAlignment.left`
`IconAlignment.center`
`IconAlignment.right`

that will simply translate to:
`WrapAlignment.left`
`WrapAlignment.center`
`WrapAlignment.right`

Im not clear how I can accomplish this with typedef.  From what I could understand I can create a map to do this but I have been failing miserably:

```
typedef IconAlignment Map<String,WrapAlignment> = ['left': WrapAlignment.left, 'center': WrapAlignment.center, 'right':WrapAlignment.right];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `typedef` creates an alias to a *type*. `WrapAlignment.left`, `WrapAlignment.center`, and `WrapAlignment.right` are not types; they are values.  However, `WrapAlignment` is a type:

```dart
typedef IconAlignment = WrapAlignment;
```

and now you can use `IconAlignment.left`, `IconAlignment.center`, and `IconAlignment.right`.

If you need to convert `String`s to `enum` values, that's a separate problem.  A `typedef` won't help you with that; it just creates type aliases.

Comment: `Error: Can't create typedef from non-function type.
typedef IconAlignment = WrapAlignment;`

Comment: @Mark [Non-`Function` `typedef`s were introduced in Dart 2.13](https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-dart-2-13-c6d547b57067).  You must modify your `pubspec.yaml` file to require a minimum Dart SDK version of 2.13.0 or later.