# How do you create custom variable types?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function in which I want to make my own custom alignment types.  I might be using the term type incorrectly so please bear with me.

But for example, in dart/flutter we have `Colors.red` or `Alignment.right`, etc...

I want to make my own called `ToolbarAlignment` which would have `ToolbarAlignment.left`, `ToolbarAlignment.center`, `ToolbarAlignment.right` variants to it.

This is being used to modify a flutter `Wrap`, so essentially I would like these to map to the `WrapAlignment` properties.

So in the end I call my class like this

```
MyCustomClass(alignment: ToolbarAlignment.center)
```

and then inside `MyCustomClass`, `ToolbarAlignment.center` gets changed into `WrapAlignment.center`

Code is very very very much appreciated, but even conceptual help is much appreciated as well.  This is my first time trying something like this so I'm a little confused where to start

Comment: so what's stopping you? What is the problem?

Comment: You can declare an enum using `enum ToolbarAlignment{ center, right, left, start, end }`. Maybe you don't need extra enum you can use WrapAlignment directly.

Comment: @user2301346 thank you! that's the start I needed.  I'm halfway there.  Any thoughts on how I would map ToolbarAlignment.left to WrapAlignment.left ?  Would you simply make an intermediary variable _intermediary and if-elses to get it there?

Comment: @Mark. You can use `Map<ToolbarAlignment, WrapAlignment> alignmentMap = {ToolbarAlignment.center: WrapAlignment.center}`. But if that's what you doing why not use WrapAlignment directly?

Comment: @user2301346 Thanks! I thought about using WrapAlignment directly, but some might find it confusing as I'm using WrapAlignment terminology in a field called ToolbarAlignment.  That and I wanted to learn about this technique

Comment: IMO you're doing extra work for little gain.  If you want a 1:1 correspondence, I'd just use the `typedef` ([as explained already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69965997/)) and, if you really want, add a `WrapAlignment toolbarAlignmentToWrapAlignment(ToolbarAlignment alignment) => alignment;` function for readability.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks I think what you are explaining in the second part is what I ultimately want.  I have to `wrap` (pun intended-- ill be here all week) my head around this some more and learn it better.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class and define static functions

```
class ToolbarAlignment{
  static const center = WrapAlignment.center;   
}
```

Access it-

```
ToolbarAlignment.center
```